# Predefined Tags For Editors

Tags: tags, tag

Is it possible to set up predefined tags in craft which can then be used as either a select list or checkbox selection by editors, so as to only give them the option of adding preset tags as opposed to adding any tag they want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really (or not without a custom solution anyway) — tags are designed to be added by anyone. You might be better off using [categories](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/categories) for this, which you can resist access to via userGroup permissions.

Comment: thanks gone down the categories route and it works exactly how I need it to. Wasn't aware you can relate multiple categories to a single entry.